# sass grid mixin for unkown elements and unknown height

Tags: css, sass, mixins, grid-layout

I wrote this sass grid mixin to use for when I want a gallery style grid with an unknown number of elements, it works greats as long as they are equal height.

```
@mixin part_of($num, $gutter_percent: $gutter_percent){
        margin-right: $gutter_percent;
        float: right;
        width: (100 - $gutter_percent * ($num - 1)) / $num;
        &:nth-of-type(#{$num}n+1){
        margin-right: 0;
        }
        &:nth-of-type(n+#{($num+1)}){
        margin-top:$gutter_percent;
        }
}
```

for the life of me I can't seem to make it work with unknown height, I know that I need to use the `clear` property somewhere but I'm not sure where.

Comment: I don't think you can easily achieve this without setting a fixed height. Have you considered using flexbox? Another solution would be javascript but i think this complicates thinks a bit because you ll have to take a sample of all your items and use the highest which does't work very good visually all the times.

Comment: @davegri Do you even know what CSS is necessary to do what you want?  Until you have that, bringing Sass into the equation is useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, I needed to add `clear:both` to every element on a new line